# Chromium depot_tools - failed download behind proxy

Tags: chromium

Running gclient behind my work's proxy doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why.

[image]

I've tried setting http_proxy and https_proxy env vars, but that didn't change anything. The only way it works for me is if I'm off my work network and the proxy env vars are unset. But, of course, ideally I'd like it to work even on my work network.

Comment: You know environment variables are case-sensitive right? I hope you're using `HTTP_PROXY` and not `http_proxy`

Comment: @luqui I tried it both ways but got the same result either way.